# Classification model for rare events when SMOTE doesn't work

Tags: python, smote

I have a data frame with rare events in the target variable- label=1 is less than 1% and I want to build a classification model.

All the classic models display poor performance, and using SMOTE or other sampling technique didn't make a difference.

Is there other successfuly techeniques or models to train on extremely rare events?

I wanted to try the GEV- generalized extreme value regression, but I didn't find a good explanation regarding the code in Python.

Does anyone familiar with this model?